# How to send data from Android to Google App Engine by http protocol?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am working on an Android project which needs to set up connection with HTTP server and upload data. Now the code has been done by others and it works on an HTTP server. However, we would like to connect it with Google App Engine. It seems only changing the server-ip, server-username... will do, but I don't know how to get the ip/username/port...of a GAE server. I am completely new to Android development. Could anyone help me based on the following code?

```
    public class ServerUploaderService extends RemoteDataService {
        private   static final String TAG                     =   "ServerUploaderService";
        private   static final String SERVER_IP               = "***.***.***.***";
        private   static final String SERVER_USERNAME         = "REMOVED";
        private   static final String SERVER_PASSWORD         = "REMOVED";
        private   static final int    SERVER_PORT             = 22;
        private   static final int    SERVER_LPORT            = 22;
        .....
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only a list of constants for what looks like connecting
to a remote machine over SSH (port 22), not HTTP.

You might want to take a step back and learn about what a [REST API](http://restcookbook.com) is , as this is the de-facto standard way of consuming services over HTTP from a mobile client. From there start with learning about how to make an [HTTP connection in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html) and finally read about [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints), as this is the standard way to expose a REST service from App Engine.

FYI, you can't connect to a port on an App Engine instance, as they are sandboxed instances that don't listen on ports or have IP addresses attached to them. The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java) are a good place to find more about how it works.